# Laravel Multiple wherein's

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

How can I do multiple wherein in laravel?

```
$devices = DB::table('foo')
              ->select('foo.*')
              ->whereIn('bar1', $request->bar1)
              ->whereIn('bar2', $request->bar2)
              ->get();
```

Above is my sample code but it is returning me an empty array.

Comment: Are `$request->bar1` and `$request->bar2` arrays? It should work without any problem if they are.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek `"select 'foo'.* from 'foo' where 'bar1' in (?) and 0 = 1"` this is what i got by calling toSql(). this is not the sql code that i should be getting right

Comment: Please edit your question and add result of `dd($request->bar2);`

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek just realized that there was a missing character in my variable and it did not show as error. so careless of me. anyway thanks for ur time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is ok to use multiple **WHERE IN** constraints in your query. The code you provided is also ok.

If you're getting no results, make sure that values of **$request->bar1** and **$request->bar2** are what you expect - they should be **arrays** of values that contain what you want your **bar1/bar2** columns to be.

You can always get the generated **SQL** by calling **toSql()** instead of **get()**, you can also inspect the values of parameters by calling **getBindings()**.

Comment: `"select 'foo'.* from 'foo' where 'bar1' in (?) and 0 = 1"` this is what i got by calling toSql(). this is not the sql code that i should be getting right

Comment: It seems your $request->bar2 is empty

Comment: Do "dd($request->all())" and paste the output.

Comment: ok just realized there was a missing character in the variable name and there was no error generated... so careless of me @_@ anyway thanks a lot for the time!